# Delete section (red delete button), UITableViewController - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to do a grouped uitableview and I have activated the edit option. I want the user to be able to delete the whole section too, not only specific rows.
So, when you click EDIT, the red minus button that shows on the left of each table cell, should show up for sections (left of the section title) too.
Anyone knows a way to do this?

Thanks in advance to everyone!
Olsi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do it out of the box. You'll need to get fancy and return a custom view in your table view delegate's `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` method. When you enter edit mode, you'll have to add a delete button to those views.

Comment: After a lot of research, I learned that's the only way to do it.

Comment: how can we add a delete button? is there special setting for it or is it just a red button?